# sql - counting result in two table

Tags: sql

I have two table, the first one contains the user data and the second one contains user wanted item list.

```
Select * FROM user
id | name
 1 | tom
 2 | may
 3 | peter

Select * FROM wantedlist
userid | item
  1    |  pen
  1    |  bag
  3    |  pen
```

I want to get the table which contains the amount of user wanted items. 
What I want:

```
id | name | totalitems
 1 | tom  |     2
 2 | may  |     0
 3 | peter|     1
```

I tried to join two table to get the table but failed.
What I tried and got:

```
id | name | totalitems
 1 | tom  |     2
 3 | peter|     1
```

The result does not contain who did not have wanted items whether using left, right, inner join. Can someone tell me what should I use?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for hte database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` user table to wanted list table, then perform a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(w.item)
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN wantedlist AS w ON u.id = w.userid
GROUP BY u.id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ffe4/1)